# Limit decimal places in a return?

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I'm new and trying to stick to basic concepts here. How do I limit the decimals in an answer pulled from a return in a different class?I'm not sure how to write `a.calculateTuition` in a price format 000.00. I couldn't find a good way to use the DecimalFormat class and `Math.round()` is not accurate enough for prices. Thanks in advance!

From the class:

```
public double creditHours;
public double calculateTuition(){
    double totalCost=0;
    double costPerHour=124.04;
    totalCost = creditHours * costPerHour;

    return totalCost;
}
```

From Main:

```
Student a=new Student();
a.setHours(3);
System.out.println("Cost is " +  a.calculateTuition());
```

Comment: I always use integers when calculating money amounts.   Use cents e.g 100 means 100 cents.

Comment: @JJF If you actually do serious financial stuff, I highly recommend using an actual framework designed for that. Basically, money is infinitely divisible. If I wish to pay you half a cent (e.g. price on fuel), I can do so

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's considered to be best practise to use `BigDecimal` with currency / money related computations because of the precision it offers.

If you decide to use BigDecimal, it also has .setScale() and many other useful methods you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following utility to round the number of decimals you want,
    public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

```
long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
value = value * factor;
long tmp = Math.round(value);
return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```